# Python list append: multiple appends per iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, append

I have a dataframe that contains many rows `row` (order of 60000) with the three fields:

1. shift: a string of 96 characters indicating the location or `'r'` (no location; e.g. `'rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrraaabbbbbbbrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr'`)
2. start: specified startingpoint (1 indexed)
3. stop: specified stoppoint (1 indexed)

Now I want to have a mapping for both location `'a'` and `'b'`. This mapping shows on which point in time, which `row` contains `a` or `b`. We thus have:

```
mapping['a'] = [[]]*96 # list of length 96 with, initially, and empty list for the row-indexes. `
mapping['b'] = [[]]*96 # list of length 96 with, initially, and empty list for the row-indexes. `

for index, row in pd_shifts.iterrows():
    for t in range(row['start']-1,row['stop']):
        loc = row['shift'][t] # either 'a' or 'b'
        if loc != 'r': # 'r' can be ignored.
            mapping[loc][t].append(index)
```

I use the above for-loops to find `loc` on moment `t`, and append it to `mapping[loc][t]`. Seems like an easy job. However, each index is added for as many times the `a` or `b` is in the string. A snippet of the output:
`1535,1535,1536,1536,1536,1536,1536,1537,1537,`

What is happening here? **Why is each index appended for as many times the `a` is in the shift?**

#### Attempts

I have checked that each row has a unique index, and that each row is iterated only once.
Also, each start point and stop point (and point in between) are visited once ('print(t)').